mavros ftp list fails "Incorrect list entry"
I have a mavros container running on my pc, connected to my local Mission Planner simulation. I start it like so and can correctly communicate with the FCU, for example, to set parameters, etc:
ros2 run mavros mavros_node --ros-args -p fcu_url:=tcp://host.docker.internal:5762

But how do I access the FCU's MAVftp? I tried the following, but it issues an error:
$ ros2 service call /mavros/ftp/list mavros_msgs/srv/FileList '{ dir_path: "/" }'

# response:

waiting for service to become available...
requester: making request: mavros_msgs.srv.FileList_Request(dir_path='/')

[ERROR] [1719235751.706373522] [mavros.ftp]: FTP: Incorrect list entry:
response:
mavros_msgs.srv.FileList_Response(list=[], success=False, r_errno=34)

When trying to access MAVftp from within Mission Planner -> config -> MAVftp, it works, I can see the FCU file system.
Is there some other way of doing it?
